# in C++, I would like to define a class object from a template, by using a typename information coming from a variable(e.g. string)

Tags: c++, templates

In C++, I would like to define a class object from a template, by using a typename information coming from a variable(e.g. string).

E.g. this is the template class:

```
template<typename mtype>
class MyClass{
private:
   mtype *a;
public:
   ....
}
```

And this is how I would like to use it:

```
void main()
{
  ....
  // read information from external sources, e.g. config file
  std::string mtype_info=ReadFromConfigFile();

  // create a MyClass object, using the translation function my_trans()
  MyClass<my_trans(mtype_info)> m;

}
```

Is something like this possible ?

### Edit:

Thank you very much for the answers so far. I am already a few steps ahead in my thinking than I was before. I can try to provide some more context here.

MyClass is a wrapper for  boost-library  random probability distribution object. MyClass allows for different classes of probability distributions ( e.g. boost::random::normal_distribution, boost::random::binomial_distribution, boost::random::beta_distribution) to be created as an "abstract" MyClass object, such that once the MyClass object is initialized, it can be used  in the same way in the code.

```
template<typename mtype>
class MyClass{
private:
    mtype* a;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    MyClass(Args&&... args) {
        a = new mtype{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    }

    ~probability_distribution() {
        delete a;
    }

    template<typename Engine, typename Seeder>
    friend class random_engine;
};
```

And the usage is:

```
MyClass<boost::random::normal_distribution<double>> m1(1,2); 
MyClass<boost::random::beta_distribution<double>> m2(2,4);
...

double r1 = g_rand.get(m1);
double r2 = g_rand.get(m2);
```

Now want I want is that the actual distribution type (the boost class reference  and initialization parameters) to come from a configuration file.

Comment: In a word, no. In a few words, what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 3):

Templates need to be instantiated at compile time before you can do something with them. They are just templates. You could write some mapping of strings to already instantiated types. The following solution assumes that you can refactor `MyClass<T>` to have a common base:

```
struct MyClassBase {
    virtual ~MyClassBase(){}
};

template<typename mtype>
class MyClass : public MyClassBase {
        mtype *a;
};
```

Then you can write a function that returns an instance of the desired instantiation of `MyClass`:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClassBase> make_MyClass(const std::string& s) {
     if ( s == "string") { return std::unique_ptr<MyClassBase>(new MyClass<std::string>()); }
     else if ( s == "int")  { return std::unique_ptr<MyClassBase>(new MyClass<int>()); }
}
```

This only works for a limited number of types (while the `MyClass` template in principle can take any template parameter).

PS: It is not really clear why `MyClass` is a tempalte. If the motivation for this was to be able to choose the type of `mytype` at runtime, then it was the wrong approach.

Comment: Like all factory patterns this probably makes most sense if the base class is an interface class with a certain number of virtual member functions, so that the user can do something with the created instances whose exact type is unknown.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I was considering to add a lengthy discussion of how already the desire to choose the type at runtime requires certain design that I dont see in OPs code. Anyhow, I decided to keep the answer short and hope OP knows what are the implications of only having a `MyClassBase*`

Comment: @Quentin My guess is the KISS principle -- the type of smart pointer to use is dependent on the application, and that discussion is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Spencer `std::unique_ptr` works for any case here, though.

Comment: And while I'm nitpicking your answer to death, I just noticed that you're missing a virtual destructor as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Templates are extracted compile-time. The variable's value can be changed runtime, so you can't use it as a template argument.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any work-around suggestion to how I could, most cleanly implement such a functionality though ? I can somewhat think of a macro function implemented using the #define mechanism ?

Comment: @user3688996 To use a *compile time* mechanism like preprocessing or templates is fundamentally impossible for data which becomes only known at *run time*. Remember: With preprocessing macros as well as templates, you could in principal simply *code everything explicitly at compile time*! Both are simply means to avoid source code duplications. For *run time* type changes you'll need polymorphism (which you can combine with templates if you must; see formerlyknownas_463035818's answer).